# How to add PHP to a CMS page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, php, cms-pages

Via **Admin > Content > Pages** I made a page that I will be using as the homepage. I want to add some PHP to this page, however this does not work (directly).

How can I do this?

I remember using a `.phtml` for this in Magento 1, but I can't remember how I did this, and things may well be changed since Magento 2.

Answer (score 3):

In your page's content section, you can insert a .phtml template file using the following:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" block_id="your_block_identifier" template="Some_Module::template.phtml"}}
```

This requires you to have a module with the template you want to use, for example: `{theme_directory}/Your_Module/template/mytemplate.phtml` and then reference it as `Your_Module::mytemplate.phtml`.

Comment: Thanks! I've added `test.phtml` in `<theme-folder>/Magento_Theme/template`. How do I get the `block_id` (`your_block_identifier`)?

Comment: That part is just a unique identifier that you assign to the block. It can be whatever you want but has to be unique to that page.

Comment: I added the file `app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>/Magento_Theme/template/html/test.phtml`. The content of the file is `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>`. After running `sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL en_US` and flushing the cache, I added `{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" block_id="homepage_block" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}. But nothing shows up. :( Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?

Comment: I mistakenly thought you could add a template through the theme directory but apparently that doesn't work. You have to add it via a module. There's tutorial for adding a module here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc. Sorry for the confusion.